# Cocos2d-x setAnimationInterval doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x, frame-rate

I try to set the max FPS in my application in Cocos2d-x with the following code:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 30);
```

It's working on iOS, but when I test it on three Android devices it's ignored, and renders frames with the standard interval (1/60).

How can I properly set the max FPS on Android using cocos2d-x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I've actually managed to kind of achieve it. You have to edit the Cocos2dxRenderer.java file and then clean and rebuild Cocos2d-x.

Here is the code :

```
public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl) {

     // FPS controlling algorithm is not accurate, and it will slow down FPS
     // on some devices. So comment FPS controlling code.



    try {
        if (loopRuntime < 40) {
            Log.wtf("RENDERER", "Sleeping for == " + (40 - loopRuntime));
            Thread.sleep(40 - loopRuntime);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //final long nowInNanoSeconds = System.nanoTime();
    //final long interval = nowInNanoSeconds - this.mLastTickInNanoSeconds;

            loopStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // should render a frame when onDrawFrame() is called or there is a
    // "ghost"
    Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender();

    loopEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    loopRuntime = (loopEnd - loopStart);

    Log.wtf("RENDERER", "loopRunTime == " + loopRuntime);

    // fps controlling
    /*if (interval < Cocos2dxRenderer.sAnimationInterval) {
        try {
            // because we render it before, so we should sleep twice time interval
            Thread.sleep((Cocos2dxRenderer.sAnimationInterval - interval) / Cocos2dxRenderer.NANOSECONDSPERMICROSECOND);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
        }
    }*/

    //this.mLastTickInNanoSeconds = nowInNanoSeconds;
}
```

Weird thing is that when I uncommented the fps control parts that were there it did nothing, and when I wrote my version it does...
Anyway, the "magic" value of 40 there gives about 35fps, but you could of course easily change it to work with values passed through setAnimationInterval();

EDIT : I moved the loopStart line to after the sleep -> the sleep time shouldn't be included in loopTime.

Answer (score 1):

That is a werid thing.But if you have two scenes play together and you are making both scenes 30 fps, although `pDirector->getAnimationInterval()`returns interval of 1/30,but you still get 60+ fps.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine ...

found from http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/setanimationinterval-does-nothing-on-android/6419/4

```
private long renderingElapsedTime;


@Override

public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl) 

{

/*
 * FPS controlling algorithm is not accurate, and it will slow down FPS
 * on some devices. So comment FPS controlling code.
 */

try {
    if (renderingElapsedTime * NANOSECONDSPERMICROSECOND < Cocos2dxRenderer.sAnimationInterval) {
        Thread.sleep((Cocos2dxRenderer.sAnimationInterval - renderingElapsedTime * NANOSECONDSPERMICROSECOND) / NANOSECONDSPERMICROSECOND);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

/*
final long nowInNanoSeconds = System.nanoTime();
final long interval = nowInNanoSeconds - this.mLastTickInNanoSeconds;
*/

// Get the timestamp when rendering started
long renderingStartedTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

// should render a frame when onDrawFrame() is called or there is a
// "ghost"
Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender();

// Calculate the elapsed time during rendering
renderingElapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - renderingStartedTimestamp);

/*
// fps controlling
if (interval < Cocos2dxRenderer.sAnimationInterval) {
    try {
        // because we render it before, so we should sleep twice time interval
        Thread.sleep((Cocos2dxRenderer.sAnimationInterval - interval) / Cocos2dxRenderer.NANOSECONDSPERMICROSECOND);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
    }
}

this.mLastTickInNanoSeconds = nowInNanoSeconds;
*/
```

}

Hope it helps